# Java scrabble game unexpected error

Tags: java, constructor

On the line where I commented "ERROR HERE" I am getting an error stating "non static variable this cannot be referenced from a non-static context".  But when I remove static from my methods, it runs and I get "Error: Main method is not static in class scrabble.Scrabble, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)".  Not sure what is causing this.

```
 package scrabble;

public class Scrabble {

class Tile{
   int value;
   char letter;

public Tile (char letter, int value) {
this.letter=letter;
this.value=value;
}
} 
private static void printTile(Tile letter) {
    System.out.print("Letter is: " + letter.letter);
    System.out.println(" and the value is " + letter.value);

}

public static void testTile() {
    Tile L1 = new Tile('z', 10); //ERROR HERE
    printTile(L1);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
testTile();
}

}
```

Comment: Did you make the `Tile` class an **inner class** of `Scrabble` on purpose? if so, you cannot create an instance of an inner class without having an instance of the outer class. Do you know what nested classes and inner classes are?

Comment: Put the word `static` in front of `class Tile`. It'll fix your issue.

Comment: @RafikElBaH'ri already helped answer it.  I needed to make my Tile class in a separate file.  Thank you both for your input!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

put the Title class in a separated file Title.java in the same package

> package scrable

and make it public. that will work for you. :)